# JQuery: How to select tr in tbody containing col elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide the rows of a table inside a table body containing col tags but I am not able to do it. If I remove the col tags from the tbody, the code works perfectly .I have a HTML code as follows

```
<table>
    <tbody id="fbody">
        <col width="10px"></col>
        <col width="10px"></col>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>fooo</td>
            <td>baar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and javascript as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#fbody").find("tr").hide();
});
```

Here is the link for the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachinbr/eb9wnkzx/9/)

Can any one let me know how I can get the tr objects inside a tbody containing col tags?

Comment: Does the `id` have to be on `tbody`? i.e. can you put an id on the `<table>`?

Comment: @Zsw yeah i can put an id on table as well

Comment: The problem is there is nothing in tbody with id (#fbody) to find, because of the cols, take a look -- http://s10.postimg.org/p1hdy924p/Capture.jpg

Comment: so you might as well give the table the id (#fbody) and hide the tr's --  $("#fbody tr").hide();

Comment: @Tasos Yeah you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Zsw yeah i can put an id on table as well –  Sachin B. R.

Put an `id` on the `<table>`.

```
<table id="ftable">
    <tbody>
        <col width="10px"></col>
        <col width="10px"></col>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>fooo</td>
            <td>baar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then hide it with the following selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ftable tr").hide();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vL6yr7mz/)

---

### Did some additional research on this

The reason that your selector wasn't working with the `id` on the `<tbody>` was because your html was not technically valid.

`<col>` should not be put inside `<tbody>`. Rather, they should be inside a `<colgroup>`. Your table was being converted behind the scene into this:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="fbody">
        </tbody><colgroup><col width="10px">
        <col width="10px">
        </colgroup><tbody><tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>fooo</td>
            <td>baar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So when you try to select on `#fbody`, you can't find anything. Instead, your table should be like this:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="10px"></col>
        <col width="10px"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody id="fbody">
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>fooo</td>
            <td>baar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now your original code will work too!

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x65js2uL/)

Answer (score 1):

`col` elements are not allowed within a `tbody`.  If you inspect the table, you'll see that the `tbody` with id "fbody" does not contain any `tr` elements.

Move the `col` elements to be direct children of `table`, and your code works as-is:

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uLs7udqy/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector to hide

```
 $("#fbody:has(col)  tr").hide();
```

Comment: This would hide all `<td>` from all tables.